# Front End Registration Form Code - Password Field Not Saving

Tags: users, forms, front-end, user-registration

I have a front end registration form which almost works perfect except that the passwords are not being set correctly.

In my functions.php I have -

```
/**
 * Registration form
 *
 */

add_action('template_redirect', 'register_a_user');
function register_a_user(){
  if(isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'register'):
    $errors = array();
    if(empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['email'])) $errors[] = 'provide a user and email';
    if(!empty($_POST['spam'])) $errors[] = 'gtfo spammer';
    if(!empty($_POST['pass1']) && !empty($_POST['pass2'])) $error[] = 'The passwords you entered do not match';

$account = esc_attr($_POST['account_type']);
    $user_login = esc_attr($_POST['user']);
    $user_email = esc_attr($_POST['email']);
 $user_pass = esc_attr($_POST['pass1']);
 $user_pass2 = esc_attr($_POST['pass2']);
    require_once(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/registration.php');

    $sanitized_user_login = sanitize_user($user_login);
    $user_email = apply_filters('user_registration_email', $user_email);

    if(!is_email($user_email)) $errors[] = 'invalid e-mail';
    elseif(email_exists($user_email)) $errors[] = 'this email is already registered, bla bla...';

    if(empty($sanitized_user_login) || !validate_username($user_login)) $errors[] = 'invalid user name';
    elseif(username_exists($sanitized_user_login)) $errors[] = 'user name already exists';

    if(empty($errors)):
 if ( $_POST['pass1'] == $_POST['pass2'] ) {

 $user_data = array (
        'user_login' => $sanitized_user_login,
        'user_password' => $user_pass,     
        'user_email' => $user_email,
        'role' => $account
    );

    // Create the user
    $user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );

} else { 
$errors[] = 'passwords dont match'; 
}


      if(!$user_id):
        $errors[] = 'registration failed...';
      else:
        wp_new_user_notification($user_id);
      endif;
    endif;

    if(!empty($errors)) define('REGISTRATION_ERROR', serialize($errors));
    else define('REGISTERED_A_USER', $user_email);
  endif;
}
```

And on my register page template --

```
<?php
  if(defined('REGISTRATION_ERROR'))
    foreach(unserialize(REGISTRATION_ERROR) as $error)
      echo "<div class=\"error\">{$error}</div>";
  // errors here, if any

  elseif(defined('REGISTERED_A_USER'))
    echo 'a email has been sent to '.REGISTERED_A_USER;
?>

<h2>REGISTER</h2>
<!-- REGISTER FORM -->
<form method="post" id="register-form" action="<?php echo add_query_arg('do', 'register'); ?>">

<!-- CHOOSE ACCOUNT TYPE AKA USER ROLE -->
<h4>Choose Account Type</h4>
<select name="account_type" class="form-control">
<option value="agent">Agent</option>
<option value="broker">Broker</option>
</select>

<!-- ENTER ACCOUNT DETAILS -->
<h4>Account Details</h4>

<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Email" />

<input type="text" name="user" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Username"/>

<input type="text" name="pass1" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Password" />

<input type="text" name="pass2" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Confirm Password" />

Delete this text
<input type="text" name="spam" class="form-control" value="spam_protection" />

<!-- REGISTER BUTTON -->
<input type="submit" value="REGISTER" />

</form>
```

Comment: Your $user_data has incorrect array key for password. It needs to be user_pass instead of user_password. I'll post this as answer if this works for you

Comment: wow, I cant believe I didnt realize that, thanks. Go ahead and post as answer. I'm sure others could find a use for the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$user_data has incorrect array key for password. It needs to be **user_pass** instead of **user_password**. For more reference please check out [wp_insert_user()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user)